# How do I grab the part of this string after a `/`?

Tags: regex, bash, grep, substring

Here is my Bash code:

```
echo "Some string/Another string" | grep -o "\/.*"
```

This returns `/Another string`.

But I do not want the `/` included in the value returned by `echo`.

How do I change the regex do accomplish this?

EDIT: I want to match everything after the `/`, no matter what is after it. `"Another string"` is not always after the `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU Grep that supports PCRE then you can use `\K` to forget the match.

```
$ echo "Some string/Another string" | grep -oP "\/\K.*"
Another string
```

Comment: To elaborate `\K` is just way to make the left hand side a lookbehind: `(?<\/).*`

Answer (score 2):

With sed :

```
$ sed 's/.*\/\(.*\)/\1/' <<< "Some string/Another string"
Another string
```

It search any characther up to next `/`, then capture and print following characters.

It may be more readable in ERE mode (`-r` option with GNU sed) and with another separator :

```
sed -r 's|.*/(.*)|\1|'
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I want to match everything after the `/`, no matter what is after it. `"Another string"` is not always after the `/`

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

With **parameter expansion**:

```
$ string='Some string/Another string'
$ echo "${string#*/}"
Another string
```

The expansion with `#` removes what comes after it from the beginning of the expanded parameter.

With **awk**:

```
$ awk -F/ '{print $2}' <<< "$string"
Another string
```

This sets the field separator to `/` and prints the second field.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with **cut** command:

If you want string between first and second occurrence of `/`

```
cut -d '/' -f 2 <<< "Some string/Another string/abc"
output: Another string
```

If you want entire string after first occurrence of `/`

```
cut -d '/' -f 2- <<< "Some string/Another string/abc"
output: Another string/abc
```